# how to include the leah PullRefreshTableviewController in a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have to include the leah pulltorefresh table view in an existing ios project. (https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh)

The existing table view is defined in a xib file and it's linked to an outlet in the controller class (a subclass of UIViewController).

My first try was to make the controller inherit of PullToRefreshTableViewController (from leah's project) and add the refresh fonction in that same controller. But it doesn't work, I have this error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "CampaignViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

Since PullToRefreshTableViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController, I think I can't make my controller inherit from it (am I right?). How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Have you included the `nib` file also to your project?

Comment: I'm not sure of which file you're talking about but I actually have a xib file for my CampaignViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating TableViewController from scratch, making it a subclass of PullToRefreshTableViewController.

It's much simpler than creating a table view in IB, connecting outlets, and then filling all necessary delegate and datasource methods.